# Starting IE process as a current user working this way but not the other way

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I want to open IE (it doesn't matter the web site it will open with), but I found out that using this code:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "http://www.google.com";
        proc.Start();
```

will start the browser as a current user, but with this code:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
        Process process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.Start();
```

it wouldn't, why is that? what is the reason?

Comment: What happens with the second code? As what user is IE opened in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in a try catch and take a look at the exception being raised, that should help find out why it is not working.

Comment: there is no exception. it will start IE but not as the current user.

Comment: @GordenGram - I'm intrigued - what user *is* it opening it as?

Comment: What user is it opening it as?

Comment: Oh, now I checked and it seems as the current user also but without the IE addons that will be included if you start the browser the regular way, suggests?